# Javadoc gradle task with Androidx library

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc, androidx

There is a task that generates Javadoc output but the problem is when we implement androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat class it causes an error. But other tasks compile with no error.

```
task generateJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + 
configurations.implementation
destinationDir = file("release/javadoc/")
failOnError false
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
options.windowTitle("API Documentation (${project.android.defaultConfig.versionName})")
}
```

The errorr is :

```
WifiManagerUtils.java:10: error: package androidx.core.app does not exist
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm still facing with this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I think the problem is this gradle task can't get the dependecies properly. The method; **classpath += configurations.implementation** seems ineffective to get dependecy permissions for some libraries.

This method gets the third-party dependecies in the right way.

```
afterEvaluate {
generateJavadoc.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
    variant.getJavaCompileProvider().get().classpath.files
})}
```

Comment: I just can't get this to work for me.  The problem is that "android.libraryVariants" does not exist.  I'm guessing that's because I'm using a later version of android build tools then you.  I'm using version 7.2.0.  When I debug the build script, android is the class BaseAppModuleExtension_Decorated, and it doesn't contain the member libraryVariants.